How to add screenshot of SpecFlow test failure using LivingDoc?
I have been searching to find how I can add a screenshot to my LivingDoc report upon test failure (PlayWright Framework). My research has led me to the code below:
    [AfterScenario]
    public async Task AfterScenario(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        if(scenario.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString().Equals("TestError")){
            await driver.GetPage().ScreenshotAsync(new Microsoft.Playwright.PageScreenshotOptions(){
                Path = "Screenshot.png",
                FullPage = true,
            });
        Console.WriteLine("SCREENSHOT[ file://" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Screenshot.png ]SCREENSHOT");
        }
    }

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong, the screenshot it not attaching
I've tried the code above and whilst the screenshot saves to the output directory, it doesn't show in the LivingDoc report

I have come across a work around which means that I make use of the ISpecFlowOutputHelper to help expose the AddAttachment method that can be used for attaching a URL which can be a local file URL pointing to the screenshot

It sounds like you have the start to a good answer to your own question. You can post an answer, just be sure to include enough information that other people with a similar problem can replicate the solution. Nothing wrong with that at all.
